# Can't activate any connection with nmcli: "device is strictly unmanaged"

Tags: network-manager, 22.10

When trying to activate a network connection using `nmcli c up Wired\ connection\ 1` I get the message `Error: Connection activation failed: No suitable device found for this connection (device lo not available because device is strictly unmanaged).`

I don't know what unmanaged nor strictly unmanaged implies. `nmcli dev show` lists only the `lo` loopback device. That doesn't really sound right, but what do I know...

I had both Wifi and Ethernet working before installing some nvidia drivers and doing a reboot. Now I have none of them.

- I tried various answers to similar questions but none of them seems to make any difference.
- I could not find how to update/upgrade the system or individual packages offline, from e.g. install media

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out a failed upgrade had installed a new kernel that all drivers must've been incompatible with, and it was apparently booting using that kernel. Using the oldest installed kernel instead restored network access, at which point the upgrade could be repaired.